# Kubuntu not logging in after restoring an rscyn-based backup

Tags: kubuntu, backup, lvm, rsync, backintime

My setup is as follows:

In an extended partition, there is a 1GB ext2 boot partition, and a LUKS crypto container. Within the container there is an LVM physical volume, with one volume group, within which are 3 logical volumes: lvRoot (12GB), lvHome (20GB) and lvSwap (20GB). On lvRoot there is Kubuntu 15.04 installed, using lvSwap as swap and lvHome as /home. I keep all of my stuff in a completely separate place, so /home is just for application data.

I do regular backups using BackInTime, which is a GUI for automated rsync backups. I back-up the boot partition and lvHome as they are, and lvRoot through an LVM snapshot. That is, I create a snapshot, mount it, back it up, unmount it, and delete it.

A few days ago I had an incident with .xsession-errors growing large and my whole lvHome got filled up and things started braking (this is apparently a known issue). I deleted the file and the system refused to log in (it just froze with the progress bar), so I booted from a live USB stick (also Kubuntu 15.04) and using BackInTime restored lvRoot and lvHome from a backup done in the times when my system was working fine.

After I did that, I still can't log in, but it looks different now: after I type in the password to my account ans hit enter, it seems to start the greeter anew - there is a short moment where the screen is black and in the left corner it displays "Starting version 219", just like it does before the login screen first appears. Also the moment I click "Log In" after typing in the password, the cursor turns into a black cross, and I don't recall this happening when it logged in normally (I could be wrong though)

I assumed that maybe the system in my last backup was already borked somehow so I restored the very oldest backup that I have - one done right after installing Kubuntu. The behavior was exactly the same after that.

Furthermore, I noticed that if I reboot from the live USB stick again after doing the restore, and mount lvHome, it appears empty. lvRoot is fine, all the files are there, but lvHome is always empty. So I assumed that maybe the logical volume lvHome itself got corrupted somehow by the .xsession-errors filling up all the space, and I was copying files to a corrupted LV, and that's why it didn't work. So I deleted lvHome, created it anew, and restored once again. The files are showing up now, but the system still refuses to log in, the same way as before. I ran fsck on lvHome and lvRoot and it says that they're clear.

I have no idea what's going on here anymore.

I was under the impression (from reading stuff like eg. [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Full_system_backup_with_rsync)), that backing up using rscync is the right way to do it, and BackInTime also has a good reputation. Furthermore, I tested this backup scheme in a virtual machine (also running Kubuntu 15.04), before I deployed it, and it worked perfectly fine.

Why is it not working now?

I did not restore /boot because I assumed it should be okay, and the system indeed boots up. Was that the mistake? Was it using LVM snapshots? Multiple sources said that the snapshots are a good idea.

What am I missing here? How do I even diagnose this?

I could just reinstall Kubuntu, but my backup scheme exists for the very reason of me not having to do reinstalls every time something breaks and I want to know why that scheme doesn't work and possibly how can I make it work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Just some thoughts: 1. did you reformat the LVM volumes? You'd need to edit /etc/fstab and replace the UUID's with the new ones. 2. You need to reinstall grub after restoring. For this you need to `chroot` into your restored system and run `update-grub`. Leave a message if you need help with `chroot` and I'll write this as an answer. Disclaimer: I'm member of BIT Dev-Team

Comment: Thank you for responding.

1. I deleted and created anew lvHome, so naturally I had to format it as well. Editing fstab was not necessary, as the volumes are mounted by name, not by UUID. I did not reformat lvRoot. Should I? Why?

2. I tried `update-grub` both chrooting from the live system, and also directly from the recovery mode of the restored system (because recovery mode works). The outcome is always the same.

Comment: No, you don't need to reformat lvRoot. Are you able to see your files in `/home` if you're in recovery mode? Does `mount` list `lvHome` as mounted?

Comment: I'm able to see the files if I mount the volume manually. In the recovery mode nothing is ever mounted by default, not even /boot. I thought this was normal, because this is my first time actually using recovery mode. Is it not normal?

Comment: You're right. I just double checked. Nothing get mounted except `/`

Comment: Any other ideas then? Or I am I going to have to reinstall the system in the end, and stop relying on BIT for system backups (which I really don't want to, because it's a nice piece of software) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, sorry this didn't came to my mind earlier. Looks like this is [Bug #58](https://github.com/bit-team/backintime/issues/58).

Permissions can't be restored from LiveCD because the LiveCD doesn't know the users. I'm about to add a new feature to read a different `/etc/passwd`. But nothing done yet. At the moment you need to run `backintime --restore` from root terminal in recovery mode. This will not change any files but fix the permissions.

First you need to mount the drives

```
mount -o remount,rw /
mount /home
mount /boot
mkdir -p /media/USER/backup_drive #or what ever path you used before
mount /dev/sdXX /media/USER/backup_drive
backintime --restore / '' 0
```

If you run BackInTime as user to backup your `/home/USER` you need to `su <USER>` and restore your home, too.

Comment: Oh, okay. But won't running `backintime --restore / '' 0` try to copy the whole `/` from backup? Are you saying that I should run it without mounting my backup drive and then it will just restore permissions?

Comment: restore also uses `rsync` which will only sync missing/changed parts. If you already restored your system in LiveCD it will do nothing (except new logs if any). You need to mount the backup drive. Forgot to mention that.

Comment: Yeah, but I have my backup on 2 different profiles, and lvRoot is done through an LVM snapshot, so `--restore /` won't really do anything. What I actually need to do then is a recovery mode, command line version of the full restore that I was doing from the live system. I will do that tomorrow and say how it went. Last question though - how does `--restore` behave in relation to profiles? I know you can specify one by using `--profile` or `--profile-id`, but if you don't do that, does it then restore from all profiles or just picks the "Main profile", or what?

Comment: Default `--profile-id` is 1 or "Main profile"

Comment: It worked. Thank you. Also, I wanted to say some things about this issue overall, but the comments here are limited, so instead I wrote on Github on the bug #58 page.